# Does anyone know how to get the color of the light?

Tags: shaders, lighting, shader-nodes

I've been trying to figure out how to create a shader in the shader node editor that will take the color of whatever light is hitting the object and put that color all over the object. My intention is to then put these in a group node and use the resulting node in the creation of my cartoon shader, as the way I pick my shadow color is also based on the color of the light source. I keep coming close, but I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of cast shadows (shadows cast on the material by other objects). I've been able to get rid of all other types of shadows, and make the light source cover the whole object, except those places where a cast shadow is and I don't know how to fix it. Does anyone have any ideas? I'm entirely self-taught with Blender, and am still very much a noob trying to learn all I can, and I don't know how to fix this and I haven't been able to find anything online.

Comment: It seems you simply need to set the color of the object white?  Then your object takes the color of the light. When it comes to shadows: if you're in a shadow, you no longer receive light, right? So there's no color of the light. If the object in shadow isn't completely black it's because there's multiple light sources - sure, technically one of the source could be a light object, and the other could be a surface bouncing light. If then you want to get the color of the original light, it seems reasonable to just make a list of all lights in the scene, because they all contribute…

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I'm trying to get the color of the light that's hitting the object, and spread that color across the whole object, even where the light isn't hitting it. This is because I plan on passing that color through an inverter, then using a multiply node to combine it with my base color, using a black and white color ramp of where the shadows are for the factor. I'm doing this so that the shadow color will dynamically change with the light color.